# GNU-EFI: How to do callbacks properly (calling convention incompatibilities)?

Tags: uefi, gnu-efi

I'm using GNU-EFI and calling UEFI functions works like a charm, thanks to the `uefi_call_wrapper()` macro, which ensures that differences in calling conventions won't be an issue.

But: What to do in the reverse case, when I want the system firmware to call my functions? This is relevant for example in case of callback functions (registered via `BS->CreateEvent()`).

Registering a callback function works fine, and it's executed successfully, but the parameters handed to such a callback function are garbage, e.g., the `VOID * Context` pointer that can be handed over.
I couldn't find any documentation regarding this (or any GNU-EFI documentation in general whatsoever).

Is there a GNU-EFI macro, stub, or anything else for this case?